# 80 byte wrapped format text file?

Tags: c#, text, byte

I am having an issue with preparing a text file for one of our vendors. They are having problems reading the file; according to what I was told, the file must be in "80 byte wrapped format". I believe they are using a mainframe system so I'm sure it has something to do with that.

When I created the file, I just used a simple `StreamWriter` with `WriteLine()` to do it, but if anyone has heard of this issue before, I could use some advice or a short code snippet on what I would need to do differently/add to accomdate their request.

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: It basically means you need to put a linebreak after every 80 characters in a line.

Comment: @Oded: Of course you will have to ensure that each character is in fact encoded in a single byte.

Comment: @Ed S - true. No multibyte characters, so you should probably restrict yourself to ASCII.

Comment: Yeah, just add Encoding.ASCII as an arg to the StreamWriter constructor.

Comment: 80 chars == number of holes you could put across in a punch card.  Use StringWriter first so you get a line, then a StreamWriter to break it up to a text file.  EBCDIC encoding might be required :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That brings back memories (of COBOL, EDI and other uglyness).

That usually means that each "record" is terminated with an 0x0d+0x0a (CRLF) or 0xa (LF) on it's own which translate to the following code:

```
writer.Write("{0}\r\n", record);
writer.Write("{0}\n", record);
```

Do not use writer.WriteLine.  In the case of 80 byte wrapped format, it depends on the vendor.  It usually means that "a record" should be max 80 bytes (inclusive of the CRLF chars) otherwise it'll blow up the input buffer on the mainframe.

Hoever, I would approach the company and ask them to provide a specification of the format they require precisely so there is no ambiguity.  They should be able to either provide this or point you to the relevant vendor's documentation on the file format.

You will also probable require a specific encoding i.e. ASCII or EBCDIC if you are unlucky.

Comment: Agreed. I'd bet on EBCDIC. By the requirement, I believe it is a z/OS system.

Answer (score 0):

I remember using 80 columns text files ... are you sure they're talking about bytes? Well, if its one byte / char it would be the same.

I would put the whole text in one string and then use a simple loop to put a linebreak after 80 chars.

Comment: Well, if a machine needs 80 cols files I'm pretty sure it does not knows Unicode :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get more information from your vendor. "80 byte wrapped" can mean several different things.

As others have pointed out, they're almost certainly expecting ASCII encoding. The "80 byte" restriction means that no physical line can be more than 80 characters long (i.e. no characters in column 80 or beyond).

A *logical* line, however, can often be longer than 80 bytes. The tricky part is how you separate the logical lines from the physical lines, and there have been any number of different formats for that.

Some I've worked with expected logical lines (i.e. records) to be terminated with a CRLF, but physical lines terminated with just a CR. Or just an LF. So a record that's 120 characters in length would be encoded as:

```
79 characters<CR>41 characters<CR><LF>
```

In some cases, all lines were terminated by CRLF, and the end of a record was signified by an empty line.

Or they might be talking about [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, although that's unlikely.

Seriously, get a better description from the vendor.